# this code should print a circle which moves in the canvas but the output is blank

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

https://jsfiddle.net/DanglingPointer/0tqg94xc/11/

HTML:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Dangling pointer</title>
        <style>
            body{
                margin:0px;
                overflow-x:hidden;
            }
        </style>
    </head>

    <body>
        <canvas></canvas>
        <script src="canvas.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

JS:

```
var canvas = document.querySelector('canvas');
canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
canvas.height = window.innerHeight;

var c = canvas.getContext('2d');



var x = 200;
var y = 200;


function animate() {
    requestAnimationFrame(animate);
    c.clearRect(0, 0, innerWidth, innerHeight);
    c.beginPath();
    c.arc(x, y, 30, 0, Math.PI * 2, false);
    c.strokeStyle = 'red';
    c.stroke();
    x += 1;
    y += 1;
}
```

this is the link to the code 
the text editor gives the following errors:

```
1   ERROR: 'document' is not defined. [no-undef]    var canvas = document.querySelector('canvas');

2   ERROR: 'window' is not defined. [no-undef]  canvas.width = window.innerWidth;

3   ERROR: 'window' is not defined. [no-undef]  canvas.height = window.innerHeight;

13  ERROR: 'animate' is defined but never used. [no-unused-vars]    function animate() {

14  ERROR: 'requestAnimationFrame' is not defined. [no-undef]   requestAnimationFrame(animate);

15  ERROR: 'innerWidth' is not defined. [no-undef]  c.clearRect(0, 0, innerWidth, innerHeight);

15  ERROR: 'innerHeight' is not defined. [no-undef] c.clearRect(0, 0, innerWidth, innerHeight);
```

Comment: As far as I can see you never call your function.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/5xam4av2/2/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing call to `animate()` see below

```js
var canvas = document.querySelector('canvas');
canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
canvas.height = window.innerHeight;

var c = canvas.getContext('2d');



var x = 200;
var y = 200;


function animate() {
  requestAnimationFrame(animate);
  c.clearRect(0, 0, innerWidth, innerHeight);
  c.beginPath();
  c.arc(x, y, 30, 0, Math.PI * 2, false);
  c.strokeStyle = 'red';
  c.stroke();
  x += 1;
  y += 1;
}
(function() {
   // your page initialization code here
   // the DOM will be available here
   animate()
})()
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>Dangling pointer</title>
  <style>
    body {
      margin: 0px;
      overflow-x: hidden;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <canvas></canvas>
  <!--  <script src="canvas.js"></script> -->
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: why is jquery used?

Comment: that was just to call the function on DOM ready you can swap it with `(function(){})` see above i updated it and removed jquery @DanglingPointer

Answer (score 0):

One of the problems in here is that you never call your animation function,
by doing `animate();` at the end of your script, after declaring the function. Also, I believe you call `window.requestAnimationFrame();` instead of `requestAnimationFrame()`, though I could be wrong. EDIT: I believe both are valid.

Comment: I see the answer below(or above) also answers this, but I suppose that this is best for being a minimalist, and having no dependencies.